# How to calculate euclidian distance from similarity matrix

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, similarities, cosine-similarity, jaccard-similarity

I have a similarity matrix but can not use it in the k-mean as input. So is there any way to convert the similarity matrix to the euclidean distance matrix?

Edit: I have Jaccard, overlap, cosine,(tfidf+cosine) similarity matrix.

Comment: could you please clarify: what 'mean' are you intending to use it as an input to? In general what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: sorry its k-mean.

Comment: if its cosine similarity, then it assumes that you are taking the dot product of 2 unit norm vectors, or converting the vectors to unit norm before taking the dot product ( i.e. ignoring the norms). in that case there is a relationship that $distance(a,b) = 2 - 2*cosinesimilarity(a,b)$ .This only holds if a,b are unit norm

Comment: This will depend on what exactly the similarities in your similarity matrix are. Note that generally you can construct a dissimilarity matrix from your similarity matrix. One way of doing this is to take the maximum similarity minus the matrix. Then you can use clustering methods for general dissimilarities such as Partitioning Around Medoids (PAM), which is pretty similar to k-means.

Comment: @ChristianHennig how can I find an optimal number of clusters for PAM? It changes when I run. I am using silhouette score.

Comment: Silhouette score would be the standard approach. Not sure what you mean by "it changes when I run".